# Visibility to Gone in Android

Tags: android, view, visibility

I am working on dynamic view. I am everything like generating Image view's id ,constraints with loop and setting all in code. I want one Pause and Start button. If I click on pause everything should be Invisible  except a play button.  Is it possible?

```
ImageView[][] imageView = new ImageView[levelHeight][levelWidth];

    //setting each imageview's id and conatraints
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {


            imageView[i][j] = new ImageView(this);
            imageView[i][j].setId(View.generateViewId());

            imageView[i][j].setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewWidth));

            mainLayout.addView(imageView[i][j]);

            ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
            constraintSet.clone(mainLayout);
            if ((i == 0) && (j == 0)) {
                constraintSet.connect(imageView[i][j].getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, mainLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
                constraintSet.connect(imageView[i][j].getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, mainLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
            }
            if (j != 0) {

                constraintSet.connect(imageView[i][j].getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, imageView[i][j - 1].getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
                constraintSet.connect(imageView[i][j].getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, imageView[i][j - 1].getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
            }
            if (i != 0) {
                //   newTopMargin=newTopMargin+viewHeight;
                constraintSet.connect(imageView[i][j].getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, imageView[i - 1][j].getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
                constraintSet.connect(imageView[i][j].getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, imageView[i - 1][j].getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
            }
            constraintSet.applyTo(mainLayout);
```

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: Sorry for that. I wont do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your 2 dimensional array  of image, and each time set each item to gone:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
 for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
   imageView[i][j].setVisibility(VIEW.GONE)
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That Worked. I just needed to declare imageView before creating activity so that that can be accessible on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Define this for every item that you want to make its visibility GONE:

```
item.visibility=View.GONE
```

Comment: that is the problem . I am using dynamic view. Generating id by View so dont know about ids .

Comment: So your problem is in finding ids not in setting visibility to GONE @ManpreetNarang